# Having issues with javascript compiling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an application Javascript file that is showing an error in the console section of VS Studio Code, it keeps saying: app.js: **The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.** and the console will not compile.

Based on my code, would you be able to tell me where I need to close in my braces? I think I might be confused.

Here is my app.js code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//specify where to find the schema
const Item = require('./models/item')
// connect and display the status 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/items', { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => { console.log("connected"); })
  .catch(() => { console.log("error connecting"); });

// use the following code on any request that matches the specified mount path
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   console.log('This line is always called');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); //can connect from any host
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS'); //allowable methods
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept');
   next();
});
app.get('/items', (req, res, next) => {
  //call mongoose method find (MongoDB db.Students.find())
  Item.find() 
    //if data is returned, send data as a response 
    .then(data => res.status(200).json(data))
    //if error, send internal server error
    .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error: ${err}');
    res.status(500).json(err);
});


  // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// serve incoming post requests to /items
app.post('/items', (req, res, next) => {
    const items = req.body;
    console.log(items.itemName + " " + items.servings);
    //sent an acknowledgment back to caller 
    res.status(201).json('Post successful');
  });


//to use this middleware in other parts of the application
module.exports=app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `app.get('/items'` function is not closed. Try this.

```js
app.get('/items', (req, res, next) => {
  //call mongoose method find (MongoDB db.Students.find())
  Item.find()
    //if data is returned, send data as a response 
    .then(data => res.status(200).json(data))
    //if error, send internal server error
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error: ${err}');
      res.status(500).json(err);
    });
});
```

But in the future, please just use an IDE of some sorts. Even just dumping your code into [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cg132wp/) will highlight this for you.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, that fix the coding syntax error (red highlights). But now I'm getting  error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context. when I try to compile. Do you know what that would mean?

Comment: Yes it says 24     get enabled(): boolean;        but this is happening on multiple lines, I was Googling just now and apparently this might be an issue with the Angular version, not sure if that's the case.

Comment: As none of the code snippets has `enabled` or `enable` in it, I would assume it is in 'models/item', however, it may be better to try a few things out and make a separate question for this.